# React Navigation logout button on TabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator

I have a `TabNavigator` inside a `StackNavigator` (in the `StackNavigator` I have the `login` view and the `TabNavigator`, which contains the other screens).
The problem is that I have to make something like a '`Logout`' button on a Tab that just redirect to the `Login` view.
If I try to simply redirect to the `LoginView`, the `TabBar` still appearing on the bottom of the screen and that's not what I want.
Is there any way to click on the `TabBar` button and return to the initial `StackNavigator`? (Like an `OnPress` property or something like that).

Here is my router

```
const tab_bar = TabNavigator({
      Home: {
        screen: HomeScreen
      },
      Logout: {
        screen: LoginView  // this just show the view but the tabBar still appearing
      },
    });

const Login = StackNavigator({
  login: {
    screen: LoginView,
  },
  List: {
    screen: tab_bar
    ,navigationOptions: {header:null}
  }
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'login'
});
```

Comment: You can use [tabBarVisible](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab#tabBarVisible) prop for the screen you don't want the tabbar show.

Comment: Better way to do it is have a logged out route stack, and logged in one. In your top level app, if loggedIn = true, show the routes for that. Pass down a screenprop that will set loggedIn:false if you want to log out and it will render the other stack

Comment: If i use tabBarVisible I can swipe over other screens, what i need is like `goBack` in the first `StackNavigator` (from the `TabNavigator` to the `loginView`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done! Using the [tabBarOnPress](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab#tabBarOnPress) property and the [Navigation Actions](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-actions#Navigate).

```
const tab_bar = TabNavigator({  // This tabNavigator is inside a stackNavigator, wich contains the 'login' view
   Home: {
     screen: Home
   },
   Logout: {
     screen: Logout     // Empty screen, useless in this specific case
       ,navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
           tabBarOnPress: (scene, jumpToIndex) => {
               return Alert.alert(   // Shows up the alert without redirecting anywhere
                   'Confirmation required'
                   ,'Do you really want to logout?'
                   ,[
                     {text: 'Accept', onPress: () => { navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'login' }))}},
                     {text: 'Cancel'}
                    ]
               );
           },
       })
    },
});
```

When the user clicks the `logout` button on the tabBar displays an Alert to confirm the action, then if the user accepts redirect to the login view.

**NOTE (22/09/2017):** To use the tabBarOnPress property download the [master branch version](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/pull/1335#issuecomment-329518635) (not the version from NPM yet).

Comment: A couple of years later and this is a blessing for me.